# Unable to display arc gis Maps in Android

Tags: android, maps, arcgis, libc

I want to display few ArcGIS map on android based on selection one at a time (from Sample available in ArcGIs Website) but I fail.

**Error I am getting is:**
**Log Tag**:dalvikvm   **Log Message**:VM aborting
**Log Tag**:libc       **Log Message**:Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000005a1 (code=-6), thread 1441

My System configuration is:
Andoid 4.4 or 5
Eclipse Juno 
Genemotion 2.3

please provide some inputs 
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Can you provide any more of your log? There's not much to go on.

Also, when you say "Android 4.4 or 5," it makes me think you're using the Android emulator, so I suggest you make sure you followed the steps at https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/emulator/ , especially checking the Use Host GPU box.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.To be more specific I am unable to display ArcGIS dynamic map in Android but same code works for Tile maps.

Error I am getting is "Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load GLMapCore from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null"

Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That helps. I suspect you can solve your problem by right-clicking your Eclipse project and choosing [ArcGIS Tools > Fix Project Properties](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/integration-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_641D1225BB664F71992B47775D86167A). That should add the libraries to the project so they won't be missing when you run the compiled app.

Comment: I have done it already but didnt help :(

Comment: Now I created new setup with android sdk5 it works :) thanks for inputs